# Safari is failing to detect developer certificate

Tags: safari, certificate

I want to create a safari extension on my Windows 7 pc. I have created a safari developer certificate properly but I couldn't really install it. After some googling, I tried importing it into Personal and Trusted Root Certification authorities. But Extension Builder keeps showing "No Safari Developer Certificate." I even revoked the certificate and created a new one. Still no luck. Can anybody help me?